# Can we compute integral $ \int_a^b \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$ without $\operatorname{arcsinh}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'd like to compute

Can we compute $J = \int_a^b \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$, without $\operatorname{arcsinh}$?

Using Maple gives answers with $\operatorname{arcsinh}$ or $\operatorname{arctanh}$. I've also tried integration by parts, but with no success. How to compute this integral (possibly without using any trigonometric/hyperbolic function)?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2%2FSqrt%5B1%2Bx%5E2%5D) yields a square root and a hyperbolic sine, why is this a problem?

Comment: Have you tried $x=\sinh t$?

Comment: It is what it is. Barring identities giving you other functions, you're not going to get a different answer.

Comment: You may substitute $x=\tan\theta$

Answer (score 4):

In fact $I$ was easier than I thought: After a substitution $v=\sqrt{t^2+4}$ and a partial fraction decomposition, one has:

$\int (\frac 14 \frac 1{v-2} - \frac 14 \frac 1{v+2}) dv,$ which gives an answer involving $\ln(v\pm2)$.

Comment: Do you know that $\operatorname{argtanh}$ is actually a logarithm?

Comment: @Bernard Yes $(1/2) \ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$, but I didn't know how to compute this integral anyway ;)

Comment: For the initial problem you mention in your post, setting $x=2\sinh t$.

Comment: @Bernard But how to compute $J = \int_a^b \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$ without making use of trigo/hyperbolic function at all? In my answer here, we see it's possible to do $I$ without any such function, so I wonder if it's possible about $J$ too?

Comment: The antiderivative of $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$  is a basic formula,and we can't help that it is $\operatorname{argsinh} x$. This being said, you can use that  $\operatorname{argsinh} x=\ln\bigl(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\bigr)$.

Comment: @Bernard That's the question: can we prove that the antiderivative of $f(x)=1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is $F(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$  *without* using trigo/hyperb functions and without just checking that $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Of course you can pull it out of your hat and check the derivative of this log is exactly $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, but it wouldn't be very natural…

Answer (score 0):

Hints for $I$ :

(1)  try to sub $x=2\tan u$

(2)  $\int \csc xdx = -\ln |\csc x + \cot x| + C$

Comment: Thank you. As seen in my other answer, one can $I$ without any trigonometric function, is it possible to compute $J$ also without any trigonometric function?

Answer (score -1):

Utilize the Euler substitution $\sqrt{1+x^2}=t+x$ to get
$dx =-\frac{t+x}tdt$ and
\begin{align}
\int \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx=- \int \frac {1}{t+x} \frac{t+x}t dt=-\ln t +C
\end{align}
Thus
$$\int_a^b \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx=-\ln\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right)\bigg|_a^b=\ln\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}-b}
$$